# PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser - parsing Javascript variables with preg_match_all

Tags: javascript, php, html, dom

I am currently using PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser to fetch data. More about the parser you can check here: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

I am working around a script which is parsing Javascript variables, and i want them as a simple text.

Here is the page which i parse:
http://www.sportsdirect.com/adidas-adi5-x-ite-mens-astro-turf-trainers-263185?colcode=26318536

Here is the code which i use for parsing:

```
<?PHP
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
$url = "http://www.sportsdirect.com/adidas-adi5-x-ite-mens-astro-turf-trainers-263185?colcode=26318536";

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
$str = curl_exec($curl);  
curl_close($curl);  

$html= str_get_html($str); 

preg_match_all('/\"SizeName\":\"([0-9]+)\"/',$str,$matches);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($matches);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

The output of this code you can check here:
http://sportsdirectbg.superweb.bg/test.php

1. First of all, how i can print this values like simple text without these Array( and these numbers [0][1][2][3] which are placed before every result ?
2. Why this scirpt is giving me results with full numbers, In example there as you can see in the output source of the page which i am parsing you can find for the javascript variable "SizeName" results like `6.5` but in my case it's printing them as simple 6, why ?
3. As you can see in the output source of the page which i am parsing after every javascript variable "SizeName" there is other javascript variable called "SellPrice" and this variable is containing the price for the size. I want to get this value also. So i can print something like this:

`$ProductSize - $ProductPrice` if you can get what i mean.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're not actually using the object created by `str_get_html`, so you're not really using the PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser at all.

Comment: Thanks, but it's not the base problem which i have :)

Comment: I disagree.  You're attempting to use regex to parse HTML, which, while there are some appropriate cases for this, is largely discouraged unless you really know what you're doing. So the base of your problem is that you're including a really helpful tool, and then completely ignoring it and trying to do it a really complex way.

Comment: I remove the line and i still receive the same output, so it did not helped me with anything at this stage, but thanks anyway ;)

Answer (score 0):

First this is almost a duplicate of one you asked earlier, [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser and Javascript selection?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25166375/2820825).

The reason you are getting whole numbers is because your regular expression is only looking for whole numbers, so change it and you will get the entire size including the decimal.  But as Patrick Q said, part of your problem is not utilizing Simple HTML DOM Parser correctly to grab those elements by ID or class name, etc, instead of through a regular expression.

Javascript parsing is not possible through simple HTML DOM Parser, as I said in the other question.  If you want, you could grab the entire page and search through for `colourVariantsInitialData` which has a JSON array of the different options, but I believe this isn't possible using the HTML DOM Parser, might be though!